# mysql -get data who complete within a year

Tags: mysql

I need to get date who finish within 1 year from a project . my project table contain 'Sdate    ' and   'Edate' which I can I need to use it to find data who finish within 1 year how do I get data within a year. For example I need to get data who have finish the project within 1 year (different is within 1 year)

This is what I have tried

```
SELECT
    concat(FName, ' ', LName) AS NAME
FROM
    Employee
WHERE
    EXISTS (
        SELECT
            DATE_SUB(Sdate, INTERVAL 1 YEAR) AS DIFF
        FROM
            Project
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the joined field based on your table column name and try below query -

```
SELECT
    concat(e.FName, ' ', e.LName) AS NAME
FROM
    Employee e
JOIN project p ON e.employeeId = p.employeeId
WHERE
    p.Sdate >= DATE_SUB(p.Edate, INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
GROUP BY
    e.id;
```

If you want to use exists function then use below query-

```
select concat(e.FName , ' ' , e.LName) as name
From Employee e
where exists(select * from product p where e.employeeId=p.employeeId and p.Sdate >= DATE_SUB(p.Edate,INTERVAL 1 YEAR))  group by e.id;
```

Comment: what should i do if i need to remain my exists funciton?

Comment: @ user130875 I have edited and written using exists function you can check that.

Comment: tq very much sir